# Format for including http link in SQL table

Tags: sqlite

I want to include hyperlinks to external sites in an SQL table (so a click takes the user to the external site). Whatever I try the result is my link gets prefixed with my own site name.

What is the format I should be using? Apologies if this is so obvious!

Comment: This is almost certainly completely unrelated to SQLite. How do you put the data in? What string shows up in the database? How do you display it to the user?

Comment: If I want to link to a page inside my site I use the form <a href="../filename.html">Link</a>. However, if I try to link to an external site using >a

Comment: Thanks Thilo: if I want to link to a page inside my own site I use the form <a href="../somepage.html">Link</a>. I put this in a cell in my table and all works just fine. However if I want to link from a table cell to an external site and I use the form <a href="http://example.com">Link</a> then the resultant link is http://example2.com/http://example.com (where example2.com is my own site where the table is hosted

Comment: Thilo: thanks for your idea to look at what is in the database. The problem is caused by the wrong use of quote marks (curly instead of straight) introduced by the CSV generator used to populate the table. Problem fixed. Thanks